# Comments clean-up - when and how to ask for it?

Tags: discussion, flagging, comments

It happens to me once in a while - under my answer appears a comment. Then I reply to it, once in a few comments editing my answer to clear the doubts and cover missed use cases. Great, that's what comments are for. But then there is an answer covering all things in comments, and a lot of outdated comments.

I could delete my own comments, but it would left other ones in void, making them look nonsensical instead of outdated. Bad idea, I think.

So should I flag my own post and ask for comments clean-up? Or remove my comments and flag the rest as outdated? Or just leave them be and don't bother?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comments that don't apply anymore should be removed: They are confusing for the future readers, who don't know anymore if the answer is updated, or it still needs to be fixed.  That is the reason you can flag comments as *obsolete*. I would rather delete your comments, and:

- Flag the single comments, when the comments are few (e.g. not more than five)
- Flag the post with a custom reason, explaining the comments are obsolete